# Categrory attribute not saved

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.2, magento2.2.0

Ive added my own color attribute for categories following this guide:
[Magento 2 DevDocs: How to add a Category Attribute](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html)

But when I save my category my field is not saved.

First I created a `InstallData.php`:

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\{
    ModuleContextInterface,
    ModuleDataSetupInterface,
    InstallDataInterface
};

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'color', [
            'type'     => 'varchar(5)',
            'label'    => 'Color',
            'input'    => 'text',
            'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Text',
            'visible'  => true,
            'default'  => '',
            'required' => false,
            'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group'    => 'Display Settings',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then Ive added my `category_form.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="display_settings">
        <field name="color" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">color</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Farbe</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string"></item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Then I run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bind/magento setup:di:compile
```

The Field is showing up in the backend at the right place but when I enter a value and click save the value is not saved.

So can anyone tell me whats wrong with my script?

Comment: Enter only 4 character into input and check is value save or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have added data type `'type' => 'varchar(5)',` in your script, so please try to add less then 5 character into input and then check your value is save or not.